# bash: make: command not found

Tags: macos, bash, makefile

I am in a directory with a Makefile, but can't use I cannot use `make`

```
bash-3.2$ make
bash: make: command not found
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make, among other things, is available through Apple's Command Line Tools. Install Command Line Tools through XCode by going to `XCode->Preferences->Downloads`

You can also download Command Line Tools without installing XCode from the Apple Developer site: https://developer.apple.com/opensource/

Comment: For the Command Line Tools, with this link, no download is available from Apple for Mac OS X 10.6.8. I suspect that it have been removed. *Thank you Apple for the planned obsolescence!*

Answer (score 4):

If you have XCode installed then @Wex's answer will get you going quickly, otherwise you don't have to install Xcode to get the command-line tools you seek.

Check this out: https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

You will want to install this one on Lion: https://github.com/downloads/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/GCC-10.7-v2.pkg

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the package you posted is outdated.

Comment: Also, you don't need XCode to download those command line tools.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I was about to download and install command line tools until I saw in the download window that you can just use:

```
xcrun make
```